# Spring Request Scope bean initialization in multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a Configuration that initializes a Request Scope bean

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {

@Bean(name = "TestBean")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public TestBean getTestBean() {
...
} 
}
```

And a ClientClass that uses the above bean.

```
@Repository
public class ClientClass {
    @Resource(name ="TestBean")
    private TestBean testBean;

    public void accessRequestBeanMethod() {
        testBean.testMethod();
    }
}
```

The request that handles HTTP request spawns n threads that individually call clientClass.accessRequestBeanMethod(). Spring intiailizes a new TestBean instance in each of the n threads. The understanding I had with Request scope is that the bean would be initialized only once for HTTP request, but seems like it is being intiantiated for every thread. I wish to implement caching of the bean for all the spawned threads in the request thread. How can I achieve it?